# Influxdb - ignore partial intervals in group by

Tags: grafana, influxdb

I feel this is a problem all users of influxdb/grafana would encounter. Any time I create a graph that shows aggregations by a time interval then the most recent and oldest intervals are cut short and the ends of the graph show incorrect values. For example, I have data coming in every 10 seconds, so I should get 360 values per hour. I wanted to create a graph showing the number of data points that come in per hour. So I have this query below that does a count by hour and run it over a 24 hour period. The problem I have is that the most recent interval is almost always less than 360 because it's not complete and the oldest interval is usually cut off so it too shows too low a value. This is pretty much always an issue for any graph I create that is grouped by a time interval. Is there a way to just leave out incomplete intervals? I'm happy for a solution in influx or grafana.

`SELECT count("wifiStrength") FROM "detailed_data"."water" WHERE $timeFilter GROUP BY time(1h) fill(null)`

For anyone who is curious, the data is from a water meter and logs water usage.

Answer (score 1):

Use smarter time ranges in the Grafana, so full hours are selected. See doc, `/h` is important here, e.g.:
[image]

Comment: Thanks that works but if the user selects a different time range then it is lost. Also it affects all graphs on the page which isn't ideal. I could move this graph to it's own page but would be good to have it along side other graphs that aren't grouped by hour